# apex select list with required = true not displaying validation error message

Tags: visualforce, validation, selectlist

Validation error message is not displaying when select list is none or blank.Also I need to hide the buttons Submit,MakeAnonymous and Cancel button when clicked on either Submit and MakeAnonymous

Apex Class:

```
  public class SeriesNewFundingEventController {

   public Id seriesId {get;set;}

    public list<Funding_Event__c> newfevenlist {get;set;}

     public list<Funding_Event__c> finalfevenlist {get;set;}

     public Funding_Event__c tempfevent = new  Funding_Event__c();

   public Funding_Event__c fevent {get;set;}

    String recType;

   String pListValue;

    public Funding_Event__c editEvent {get;set;} 

    Public Boolean showFields {get;set;} 

   Public set<Id>fIds = new set<Id>();

     public SeriesNewFundingEventController(){

    seriesId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
     system.debug('....'+seriesId); 
     fevent = new Funding_Event__c();
         showFields = false;
     }

   public String getFundingLevelSelected() {
     return pListValue;
     } 

    public void setFundingLevelSelected(String pListValue) {
      this.pListValue= pListValue;
      }

public List<SelectOption> getPickListValue()
{
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
  Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Funding_Event__c.Funding_Level__c.getDescribe();
  List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
  options.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
  for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
  {
    if(f.getValue() != 'Organization')
    {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
     }
   } 
   return options;           
 }

public String getParam(String name) {
    return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(name);   
}


      public PageReference Save(){
   newfevenlist = new list<Funding_Event__c>();
    system.debug('.....'+fevent);
    fevent.Series__c = seriesId;
      if(fevent.Grantor__c == null) {
        fevent.Grantor__c.addError('Grantor is required.');
        return null;
      }
     else{ 
     showFields = true;
     Funding_Event_Controller__c fec = new Funding_Event_Controller__c(Amount__c =                fevent.Amount__c,Status__c = fevent.Status__c);
   insert fec;
  Id rectype=[SELECT ID, name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Funding_Event__c' and name='External'].Id;

 if(fevent.Number_of_years_of_the_Funding_Event__c == 1 ){
   system.debug('...pListValue...'+pListValue);
  if(pListValue== null){
     apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select   Funding Level'));
    return null;       
  }
  else
  {
 fevent.Funding_Level__c = pListValue;
 }
  fevent.RecordTypeId= rectype;
  fevent.Funding_Event_Controller__c = fec.Id;
  newfevenlist.add(fevent);
  insert newfevenlist;
}
else
 {
   if(fevent.Number_of_years_of_the_Funding_Event__c>1){
     Integer totalYears = (fevent.Number_of_years_of_the_Funding_Event__c).intValue();
     for(integer i=0;i<totalYears;i++){
      tempfevent.RecordTypeId = rectype;
      tempfevent.Grantee__c = fevent.Grantee__c;
      tempfevent.Grantor__c = fevent.Grantor__c;
      tempfevent.Funding_Vehicle__c = fevent.Funding_Vehicle__c;
      tempfevent.Project__c = fevent.Project__c;
      tempfevent.Program__c = fevent.Program__c;
    system.debug('...pListValue...'+pListValue);
      if(pListValue== null){
       apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select Funding Level'));
       return null;       
        }
      else
       {
       tempfevent.Funding_Level__c = pListValue;
       }
      tempfevent.Status__c = fevent.Status__c;
      tempfevent.Series__c = seriesId;
       tempfevent.Funding_Event_Controller__c = fec.Id;
      newfevenlist.add(tempfevent);
      tempfevent = new Funding_Event__c();
   }
   insert newfevenlist;
  } 
 } 
}

public PageReference Cancel(){
 return null;
}

public PageReference MakeAnonymous(){

 Account account = new Account(Name='Anon',Anonymous__c = true);
 insert account;

}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
    <apex:page Controller="SeriesNewFundingEventController">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="New Funding Event" mode="edit">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageblockButtons location="top">
    <apex:commandButton value="Make Anonymous" action="{!MakeAnonymous}"/>  
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" reRender="fields">
    </apex:commandButton>
    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" immediate="true">
    </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:pageblockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="fields">
          <apex:inputField value="{!fevent.Grantee__c}" rendered="{!showFields==false}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!fevent.Grantor__c}" rendered="{!showFields==false}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Funding Level" /> 
       <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
       <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
       <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!FundingLevelSelected}" styleClass="form-select" rendered="{!showFields==false}" required="true">
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!PickListValue}"/>
       </apex:selectList>
       </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

      <apex:inputField value="{!fevent.Program__c}" rendered="{!showFields==false}"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!fevent.Project__c}" rendered="{!showFields==false}"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!fevent.Status__c}" rendered="{!showFields==false}" required="true"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!fevent.Fiscal_Year__c}" rendered="{!showFields==false}" required="true"/>

      <apex:outputField value="{!fevent.Grantee__c}" rendered="{!showFields==true}"/>
      <apex:outputField value="{!fevent.Grantor__c}" rendered="{!showFields==true}"/>
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!showFields==true}">
         <apex:outputLabel value="Funding Level" /> 
         <apex:outputText >{!fevent.Funding_Level__c}</apex:outputText>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      <apex:outputField value="{!fevent.Program__c}" rendered="{!showFields==true}"/>
      <apex:outputField value="{!fevent.Project__c}" rendered="{!showFields==true}"/>
      <apex:outputField value="{!fevent.Status__c}" rendered="{!showFields==true}"/>
      <apex:outputField value="{!fevent.Fiscal_Year__c}" rendered="{!showFields==true}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rerender` has only one target: `fields`. So only that piece of page will reflect the changes. Either remove the "rerender" completely (full page refresh) or provide a list of ids:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm

> The ID of one or more components that are redrawn when the result of
>   an AJAX update request returns to the client. This value can be a
>   single ID, a comma-separated list of IDs, or a merge field expression
>   for a list or collection of IDs.

```
<apex:pageMessages id="messages"/>
(...)
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" reRender="messages,fields">
```

Similarly you'll have to target the container (parent tag) of all your buttons you want to hide.

P.S. Use `<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">` to hold the buttons - much nicer result, similar to native SF pages.